# How can I improve my "if and else if" VBA? code

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to understand the if and else if in VBA but my code doesn't work. Could you advise what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub columnA()
Dim r As Range
Dim src As Worksheet
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim pasteRange As Range
Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report")

lastRow = src.Range("D" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set copyRange = src.Range("D3:D" & lastRow)
Set pasteRange = src.Range("A3:A" & lastRow)

If copyRange = "Updates" Then
pasteRange = "Post-Edit"
ElseIf copyRange = "New Product Translations" Then
pasteRange = "Post-Edit"
ElseIf copyRange = "Misc" Then
pasteRange = "Human"
ElseIf copyRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

What I want to do is to insert Post-Edit or Human in column A if text in column D matches criteria so if text in column D is **Update** or **New New Product Translations** then cell in column A should be **Post-Edit**, if cell in column D contains **Misc** then I want to insert **Human** in column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a formula rather than `If..Else` or `Select Case`.
The formula, if typed directly, would be `=IF(OR($D3="Updates",$D3="New Product Translations"),"Post-Edit",IF($D3="Misc","Human",""))`.

Within your code it would be:

```
Sub columnA()

    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim formulaRange As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report")
    lastrow = src.Range("D" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set formulaRange = src.Range("A3:A" & lastrow)

    formulaRange.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(OR(RC4=""Updates"",RC4=""New Product Translations""),""Post-Edit"",IF(RC4=""Misc"",""Human"",""""))"

    'Replace formula with values.
    formulaRange = formulaRange.Value

End Sub
```

If you have the lookups in a table, for example your values to find in `H1:H3` and your looked-up values in `I1:I3`, you could use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,$H$1:$I$3,2,FALSE),"")`.

The formula in VBA would be:

```
formulaRange.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC4,R1C8:R3C9,2,FALSE),"""")"
```

Comment: I've checked this code and it works perfectly fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can switch from `If` to `Select Case`, see code below:

```
Select Case copyRange
    Case "Updates", "New Product Translations"
        pasteRange = "Post-Edit"

    Case "Misc"
        pasteRange = "Human"

End Select
```

---

***Edit 1***: Full code edited

```
Option Explicit

Sub columnA()

Dim R As Range
Dim src As Worksheet
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim pasteRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report")
With src
    LastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set copyRange = .Range("D3:D" & LastRow)
    Set pasteRange = .Range("A3:A" & LastRow)
End With

If Not copyRange Is Nothing Then
    For Each R In copyRange
        Select Case R.Value
            Case "Updates", "New Product Translations"
                R.Offset(, -3).Value = "Post-Edit" ' use offset of 3 columns to put the value in column "A"

            Case "Misc"
                R.Offset(, -3).Value = "Human"

        End Select
    Next R
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, however, I also get run-time'13' error type mismatch

Comment: If copyRange = "Updates" Or copyRange = "New Product Translations",I'd like to implement this in the whole table (from A3 to the last row)

Comment: @Adrian  I don't have any If in my code, only Select, did you copy my code instead of yours ?

Comment: ahh apologies for this, the eror is in this line:     Case "Updates", "New Product Translations"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean condition **(or)** in the `If` like this:

```
If copyRange = "Updates" Or copyRange = "New Product Translations" Then
    pasteRange = "Post-Edit"
ElseIf copyRange = "Misc" Then
    pasteRange = "Human"
ElseIf copyRange Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The above code will work, if the cell range is consisted of one cell. For multiples, you should think of  a business logic what exactly do you want to compare. However, if you decide to compare only the first one, this will do the job:

```
If CopyRange.Cells(1,1) = "Updates"
```

Make sure to change it everywhere correspondingly. `pasteRange = "Something"` is ok.

---

Concerning what you are doing wrong - `copyRange` cannot be Nothing, you are setting it to a range a bit above. However, its cells can be empty.

To check this, try like following:
`ElseIf copyRange.Cells(1,1) = vbNullString`

Thus you will check the first cell in the range for being empty.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I've tried to run your code but I get run-time'13' error type mismatch

Comment: @Adrian - where?

Comment: If copyRange = "Updates" Or copyRange = "New Product Translations" Then

Comment: @Adrian - that is because you are comparing plenty of cells together. You should compare one cell only. E.g. `If CopyRange.Cells(1,1) = "Updates"` will work, if you want to compare the first cell of the range.

Comment: so what should I do if I want to implement this code to the table with plenty of cells? The macro is supposted to check all cells from D3 to the last row and insert text from A3 to the last row

Comment: @Adrian - You need a `for-each loop` there, comparing cell by cell. Or  a nice Excel formula. https://www.google.com/search?q=for+each+loop+range+vba&oq=for+each+loop+range+vba&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1j0j0i8i30k1l2.6493.7833.0.8590.6.6.0.0.0.0.106.494.5j1.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.4.322...0i13k1.eCh5x7SsLJY